# Sort based on last has_many record in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Student` model and a `Gpa` model. `Student` has_many `Gpa`. How would I sort students based on their most recently created gpa record's `value` attribute?

*NOTE: I don't want to sort an individual student's GPAs based on the created date. I would like to pull ALL students and sort them based on their most recent GPA record*

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gpas
end

@students = Student.order(...)
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using ActiveRecord

Comment: No -- PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL ... ?

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm using MySQL

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I've updated my question

Comment: can u put an example what exactly do u want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

assuming the gpas timestamp is `updated_at`

```
Student.joins(:gpas).order('gpas.updated_at DESC').uniq
```

To include students without gpas

```
#references is rails 4; works in rails 3 without it
Student.includes(:gpas).order('gpas.updated_at DESC').references(:gpas).uniq
```

---

if you dont like the `distinct` that `uniq` creates, you can use some raw sql

```
Student.find_by_sql("SELECT students.* FROM students
INNER JOIN gpas ON gpas.student_id = students.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN gpas AS future ON future.student_id = gpas.student_id
  AND future.updated_at > gpas.updated_at
WHERE future.id IS NULL ORDER BY gpas.updated_at DESC")
# or some pretty raw arel
gpa_table = Gpa.arel_table
on = Arel::Nodes::On.new(
  Arel::Nodes::Equality.new(gpa_table[:student_id], Student.arel_table[:id])
)
inner_join = Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin.new(gpa_table, on)
future_gpa_table = Gpa.arel_table.alias("future")
on = Arel::Nodes::On.new(
  Arel::Nodes::Equality.new(future_gpa_table[:student_id], gpa_table[:student_id]).\
  and(future_gpa_table[:updated_at].gt(gpa_table[:updated_at])
  )
)
outer_join = Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(future_gpa_table, on)
# get results
Student.joins(inner_join).joins(outer_join).where("future.id IS NULL").\
order('gpas.updated_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that there's a way of achieving this in any kind of convenient and mostly-ruby way. The SQL required for an efficient implementation probably requires an order based on join -- something like ...

```
select
  ...
from
  students
order by 
  (  select gpas.value
       from gpas
      where gpas.student_id = student.id
   order by gpas.as_of_date desc
      limit 1)
```

I'm not sure if that's legal in MySQL, but if it is you could probably just:

```
Student.order("(select gpas.value from gpas where gpas.student_id = student.id order by gpas.as_of_date desc limit 1)")
```

On the other hand, it seems like the last value would be an important one, so you might like to implement a callback on gpas to set a "last_gpa_id" or "last_gpa_value" in the students table to make this common join more efficient.

Then of course the implementation would be trivial.

Comment: Well, I don't think using `select` in order by clause is very optimal though. However, cache `last_gpa_id` or `last_gpa_value` seem like a best solution for me.

Comment: @j03w it depends on the query optimiser. It has the theoretical choice to implement a correlated subquery as a join. It would be interesting to see the execution plan, but I'd expect it to perform pretty well.

Comment: so I created a dummy app to simulate this and this is the query plan: http://pastebin.com/MjCrAuhM

And I think you're right!

Comment: I think you might be missing the order by inside the subquery that determines which GPA record to use?

Answer (score 1):

`@students = Student.includes(:gpas).order('gpas.value DESC')`

Still it's important to note that this will include Students, who has got no `gpas`. But you can filter that easly out with `@students.delete_if{ |s| s.gpas.blank? }`

Comment: Yes it's right. I meant .includes. It makes a LEFT OUTER JOIN which disables the negative effect of having multiple instance of same items in .joins. Try it!

Comment: Oh, interesting. And I'm irritated that includes invokes eager loading as a separate query, or a left outer join under other circumstances?

Comment: Could you edit your question please? I don't understand what you asking.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like

```
Student.joins(:gpas).order("gpas.value DESC")
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I end up w/ multiple instances of the same `Student` (because then have multiple gpa records).

Comment: how about adding a DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding some options to the relationships in your models.

Something like:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gpas, order: "value DESC", conditions: "foo = bar" #<-whatever conditions you want here
end

class Gpa < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student 
end
```

Using options, all you have to do make a call and let Rails do most of the heavy lifting.

If you get stumped, there are several more options here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Just do a keyword search on the page for "The has_and_belongs_to_many association supports these options:"

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.
Try this SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE id IN 
        (SELECT student_id 
            FROM gpa 
            GROUP BY student_id 
            ORDER BY created_at DESC);
```

Comment: This doesn't order the students. records are returned ordered by id.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you could try this method:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :gpas

  def self.by_last_gpas
    sql = <<-SQL
      select students.*,
        (
          select gpas.created_at from gpas where student_id=students.id
          order by gpas.created_at desc
          limit 1
        ) as last_created_at
      from students
      order by last_created_at desc
    SQL
    Student.find_by_sql(sql)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirty:**

You can somehow implement a query like this to fetch AR objects you need:

```
select s.* from students s, gpas g 
  where s.id = gpas.student_id 
  and gpas.id in (select max(id) from gpas group by student_id)
  order by gpas.value
```

Assuming that id is higher for records with higher created_at.

**OR**

**Nicer way:**

I assume, you'll need student's last GPA score very often. Why not add a new column `:last_gpa_score` to Student model?

You can use callback to keep this field consistent and autofilled, i. e.:

```
class Gpa < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  after_save :update_student_last_score

  private
    def update_student_last_score
      self.student.update_last_gpa_score
    end
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gpas

  def update_last_gpa_score
    self.last_gpa_score = self.gpas.order("created_at DESC").first.value
  end
end
```

Then you can do whatever you like with last_gpa_score field on student.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to adjust the table names and column names to match your DB.

```
SELECT s.*, g.*
  FROM (SELECT studentId, MAX(gpaDate) as gpaDate FROM gpas GROUP BY studentId) maxgpa
  JOIN gpas g
    ON g.studentid = maxgpa.studentId
   AND g.gpaDate   = maxgpa.gpaDate
  JOIN students s
    ON s.studentId = g.studentId
 ORDER g.gpaDate DESC
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a `last_gpa` method to get the last GPA created and then perform a standard Ruby sort.

```
def last_gpa
  a.gpas.order(:order=>"created_at DESC").first
end


Student.all.sort { |a, b| a.last_gpa <=> b.last_gpa }
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient, this will retrieve all students, and then for each retrieve all gpa. Imho you would want to leverage the power of the database.